# Push Services certificate not appearing in "My Certificates"

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I have followed all of the instructions for configuring Push Notifications as described in: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html

When I come to the final section: Installing a Client SSL Signing Identity on the Server, the IOS Push Services certificate only appears in Certificates and not in "My Certificates".

I have tried copy/paste and import/export into "My Certificates" and cannot get it to appear there in order to export a .p12 file.

Everything looks fine in xcode and in my developer account so I am quite stumped... any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

This is probably because the certificate is getting added to System Keychain. Instead of double clicking and adding it, drag and drop it under 'Login' . You will be able to export it after that

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but, unfortunately, the certificate is already in the login... I did try to remove the certificate and drag and drop back into login but it still does not appear in "My Certificates".

Comment: I have this issue as well. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

I got this issue when I came back to use a Push Certificate (to create a .p12) that I had created **a good while back** and it would not show up.

I came to realise that -

- I did not have the matching private key on my system that was originally used to create it.  You can tell this as the arrow next to the certificate in keychain was not showing as it could not match it up with the required private key.

[image]

Recreating the certificate from scratch resolved this.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed same issue by just dragging .cer file into keychain window when it showed list of my certificates. When I double clicked this file then keychain imported certificate into system certificates.

So you'll need to remove certificate from system, select "my certificates" in sidebar and drag .cer file into list of certificates

Answer (score 1):

Since these answers didn't fully resolve the issue for me I'll add my experience to this discussion as well.  In my case, the Intermediate Certificate had somehow been removed from my system.

To resolve this, open your Apple Developer Console and under All Certificates choose to create a new certificate.  At the bottom of the next screen you will see the download link for the Intermediate Certificate.  Once I installed that, I dragged the .cer files into Keychain and the new certificates appeared correctly under My Certificates.  From there I was able to export password protected .p12 files.

[image: Intermediate Certificate download button]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by revoking my current license and generating a new one (there were some issues with the Apple developer site in Chrome so switched to Safari... not sure if that helped or not).  Still not sure what caused the problem to begin with...